# How to define prerequisite for automatic variable in Makefile?

Tags: makefile

How to modify my `Makefile` to generate `1.bar`, `2.bar` and `3.bar` by typing `make all`?

The problem is that `all` depends on `$(bars)` and it is empty unless I first run `make foo`.

```
foo:
    touch 1.foo 2.foo 3.foo

bars = $(patsubst %.foo,%.bar,$(wildcard *.foo))

%.bar: %.foo
    cp $< $@

all: $(bars)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to list the files `*.foo` in your makefile:

```
foos = 1.foo 2.foo 3.foo

foo:
        touch $(foos)

bars = $(foos:.foo=.bar)

...
```

You have to have *some* starting point in your makefile.  Make cannot infer the list of things to build starting from absolutely no information at all.

If you don't know what the output will be from a command the simplest way do it is with recursive make.  Something like this:

```
all: geotiff.file
        gdal_retile.py $<
        $(MAKE) output

output: $(patsubst %.foo,%.bar,$(wildcard *.foo))

%.bar: %.foo
        cp $< $@
```

Comment: In my real case *.foo files are generated with "random" names and there are hundreds of them. I think it is a common thing

Comment: How are they generated?  What are the generated from?  I don't think it's actually that common.  Most uses of make are trying to turn some known set of files into another set of files.

Comment: It is generated by splitting one big GeoTIFF to small tiles using `gdal_retile.py`.